# firebase cloud functions iterate over collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am building a forum, and when a person comments on a thread, I would like to email everyone that someone has added a comment.  This requires iterating over a firestore collection.  How do I do this using firebase cloud functions?

```
exports.onCommentCreation = functions.firestore.document('/forum/threads/threads/{threadId}/comments/{commentId}')
 .onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {

     var commentDataSnap = snapshot; 

     var threadId = context.params.threadId; 
     var commentId = context.params.commentId; 

     // call to admin.firestore().collection does not exist
     var comments = await admin.firestore().collection('/forum/threads/threads/{threadId}/comments/');

     // iterate over collection
 });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call to admin.firestore().collection does not exist"??? How do you import `admin`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-8_5 shows how to iterate through a collection

Comment: Have you tried `\`/forum/threads/threads/${threadId}/comments/\`` in your collection query?

Comment: the answer worked, the call to collection works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run get query, not sure what is admin here, but you can do like this:

```
const citiesRef = db.collection('cities'); // pass your collection name
const snapshot = await citiesRef.where('capital', '==', true).get(); // query collection
if (snapshot.empty) {
  console.log('No matching documents.');
  return;
}  

snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

You can check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-8_5) link, for more details.

Also, I would suggest you go through [this link](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-firestore) to correctly set up the cloud function for firestore if there are any issues with it.

Comment: ok thanks, this worked.  I was able to iterate for the collection snapshot